# Vaadin web application

Tags: java

I am creating a web application for an enterprise and I would like to improve my way of coding, know what I do wrong and what I do well. I'll leave the main class' code here:

```
package com.puntobile;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonIOException;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressHandler;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.client.ui.layout.Margins;
import com.vaadin.data.Property.ValueChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.data.Property.ValueChangeListener;
import com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer;
import com.vaadin.event.Action;
import com.vaadin.event.Action.Handler;
import com.vaadin.event.ShortcutAction;
import com.vaadin.server.*;
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.datefield.Resolution;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener;
import com.vaadin.ui.Upload.Receiver;
import com.vaadin.ui.Upload.SucceededEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.Upload.SucceededListener;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import org.quartz.*;

@Theme("puntobiletheme")
public class PuntobileUI extends UI implements Receiver, SucceededListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final String[] fieldNames = { "Nombre", "IP", "Directorio",
    "Estado" };

    public static PuntobileUI INSTANCE;

    Table signs = new Table("Signs");
    IndexedContainer signsContainer = new IndexedContainer();

    List<Sign> signList = new ArrayList<Sign>();

    Table schedule = new Table();

    String owner = "guest";

    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        INSTANCE = this;
        loadUsers();
        FormLayout loginLayout = new FormLayout();
        this.setContent(loginLayout);
        Label lblLogin = new Label("Iniciar sesión");
        lblLogin.setStyleName("boldLabel");
        final TextField username = new TextField("Nombre de usuario: ");
        final PasswordField password = new PasswordField("Contraseña: ");
        Button btnLogin = new Button("Iniciar sesión");
        btnLogin.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8727890390426574530L;

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                boolean worked = false;
                for(User u : userList)
                    if ((username.getValue().equals(u.username) && password
                            .getValue().equals(u.password))) {
                        initLayout(username.getValue());
                        initSigns();
                        initSchedule();
                        worked = true;
                    } else {

                    }
                if(!worked) Notification.show("Usuario o contraseña erróneos",
                        Notification.Type.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        loginLayout.setMargin(true);
        loginLayout.addComponent(lblLogin);
        loginLayout.addComponent(username);
        loginLayout.addComponent(password);
        loginLayout.addComponent(btnLogin);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private void initLayout(final String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
        HorizontalSplitPanel splitPanel = new HorizontalSplitPanel();
        this.setContent(splitPanel);
        VerticalLayout leftLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        leftLayout.addComponent(signs);
        Button btnManage = new Button("Administrar cuentas");
        BrowserWindowOpener popupOpener = new BrowserWindowOpener(UserManager.class);
        popupOpener.extend(btnManage);
        Button btnDel = new Button("Borrar");
        btnDel.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                if(signs.getValue() != null)
                    signList.remove(((Integer) signs.getValue()) - 1);
                refreshSigns();
            }
        });
        HorizontalLayout bottomLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        bottomLayout.addComponent(btnDel);
        if (this.owner.equals("PuntoBile"))
            bottomLayout.addComponent(btnManage);
        leftLayout.addComponent(bottomLayout);
        splitPanel.addComponent(leftLayout);
        signs.setSizeFull();

        VerticalLayout rightLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        splitPanel.addComponent(rightLayout);
        rightLayout.setMargin(true);

        FormLayout addLayout = new FormLayout();
        addLayout.setMargin(true);
        rightLayout.addComponent(addLayout);
        Label lblAdd = new Label("Añadir");
        lblAdd.setStyleName("boldLabel");
        addLayout.addComponent(lblAdd);

        final TextField txtIP = new TextField("IP: ");
        final TextField txtName = new TextField("Nombre: ");
        final TextField txtRoot = new TextField("Directorio: ");
        Button btnAdd = new Button("Añadir");
        btnAdd.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                signList.add(new Sign(txtIP.getValue(), txtName.getValue(),
                        new File(txtRoot.getValue()), owner));
                txtIP.setValue("");
                txtName.setValue("");
                txtRoot.setValue("");
                refreshSigns();
                saveSigns();
            }
        });
        addLayout.addComponent(txtName);
        addLayout.addComponent(txtRoot);
        addLayout.addComponent(txtIP);
        addLayout.addComponent(btnAdd);

        VerticalLayout scheduleLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        Label lblSchedule = new Label("Programación");
        lblSchedule.setStyleName("boldLabel");
        scheduleLayout.addComponent(lblSchedule);
        scheduleLayout.addComponent(schedule);
        rightLayout.addComponent(scheduleLayout);

        FormLayout uploadLayout = new FormLayout();
        Label lblUpload = new Label("Subir vídeo");
        lblUpload.setStyleName("boldLabel");
        uploadLayout.addComponent(lblUpload);
        Upload upload = new Upload(null, this);
        upload.setButtonCaption("Subir");
        upload.addSucceededListener(this);
        uploadLayout.addComponent(upload);
        rightLayout.addComponent(uploadLayout);

        FormLayout schedulePlayLayout = new FormLayout();
        Label lblSchedulePlay = new Label("Programar un vídeo");
        lblSchedulePlay.setStyleName("boldLabel");
        schedulePlayLayout.addComponent(lblSchedulePlay);
        final ComboBox cbVideos = new ComboBox("Elige un vídeo: ");
        signs.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                cbVideos.removeAllItems();
                if (signs.getValue() != null && signList.get((Integer) signs.getValue() - 1).root
                        .listFiles() != null)
                    for (File f : signList.get((Integer) signs.getValue() - 1).root
                            .listFiles())
                        cbVideos.addItem(f.getName());
            }
        });

        schedulePlayLayout.addComponent(cbVideos);
        final InlineDateField date = new InlineDateField("Horario: ");
        date.setValue(new Date());
        date.setResolution(Resolution.MINUTE);
        schedulePlayLayout.addComponent(date);
        ComboBox cbRepeat = new ComboBox("Repetir: ");
        cbRepeat.addItem("Nunca");
        cbRepeat.addItem("Cada 24 horas");
        Button btnAddSchedule = new Button("Añadir");
        btnAddSchedule.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                //TODO: Add schedules
            }
        });
        rightLayout.addComponent(schedulePlayLayout);
    }

    private void initSigns() {
        this.signsContainer.addContainerProperty(fieldNames[0], String.class,
                fieldNames[0]);
        this.signsContainer.addContainerProperty(fieldNames[1], String.class,
                fieldNames[1]);
        this.signsContainer.addContainerProperty(fieldNames[2], String.class,
                fieldNames[2]);
        this.signsContainer
        .addContainerProperty(fieldNames[3], Image.class, new Image(
                "Conectado", new ThemeResource("icons/accept16.png")));
        signs.setContainerDataSource(signsContainer);
        signs.setVisibleColumns(fieldNames);
        signs.setSelectable(true);

        loadSigns();
    }

    private void initSchedule() {
        schedule.addContainerProperty("Horario", String.class, "Horario");
        schedule.addContainerProperty("Video", String.class, "Video");
        schedule.setVisibleColumns(new String[] { "Horario", "Video" });
        schedule.setSizeFull();
        schedule.setSortEnabled(false);
        schedule.setPageLength(schedule.size());
        schedule.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                schedule.removeAllItems();
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void refreshSigns() {
        signs.removeAllItems();
        signsContainer = new IndexedContainer();
        this.signsContainer.addContainerProperty(fieldNames[0], String.class,
                fieldNames[0]);
        this.signsContainer.addContainerProperty(fieldNames[1], String.class,
                fieldNames[1]);
        this.signsContainer.addContainerProperty(fieldNames[2], String.class,
                fieldNames[2]);
        this.signsContainer
        .addContainerProperty(fieldNames[3], Image.class, new Image(
                "Conectado", new ThemeResource("icons/accept16.png")));
        signs.setContainerDataSource(signsContainer);
        for (Sign s : signList) {
            if (s.owner.equals(this.owner) || this.owner.equals("PuntoBile")) {
                Object id = signsContainer.addItem();
                this.signsContainer.getContainerProperty(id, fieldNames[0])
                .setValue(s.nickname);
                this.signsContainer.getContainerProperty(id, fieldNames[1])
                .setValue(s.url);
                this.signsContainer.getContainerProperty(id, fieldNames[2])
                .setValue(s.root.getPath());
                if (s.isOnline())
                    this.signsContainer.getContainerProperty(id, fieldNames[3])
                    .setValue(
                            new Image("Conectado", new ThemeResource(
                                    "icons/accept16.png")));
                else
                    this.signsContainer.getContainerProperty(id, fieldNames[3])
                    .setValue(
                            new Image("Conectado", new ThemeResource(
                                    "icons/stop16.png")));
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveSigns() {
        File f = new File("signs.json");
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
            bw.write(new Gson().toJson(this.signList));
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Notification.show("Error al crear la base de datos en "
                    + f.getAbsolutePath());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void loadSigns() {
        try {
            Type t = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Sign>>() {
            }.getType();
            signList = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader("signs.json"), t);
            if (signList == null)
                signList = new ArrayList<Sign>();
            refreshSigns();
        } catch (JsonIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void saveUsers() {
        File f = new File("users.json");
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
            bw.write(new Gson().toJson(this.userList));
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Notification.show("Error al crear la base de datos en "
                    + f.getAbsolutePath());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void loadUsers() {
        try {
            Type t = new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>() {
            }.getType();
            userList = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader("users.json"), t);
            if (userList == null)
                userList = new ArrayList<User>();
            refreshSigns();
        } catch (JsonIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    File file;

    @Override
    public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            file = new File("/tmp/uploads/" + filename);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (final java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            Notification.show("No se ha podido encontrar el archivo",
                    Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return null;
        }
        return fos;
    }

    @Override
    public void uploadSucceeded(SucceededEvent event) {
        file.renameTo(new File(
                signList.get((Integer) signs.getValue() - 1).root
                + File.separator + file.getName()));
        Notification.show("Video subido");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some comments: (I bet other reviewers can find more)

**Private and final**

As much as possible, fields should be marked with `private` and `final`. One of these fields is `signs`. There are several others that have the "default" visibility when they can probably be marked **private**.

```
private final Table signs = new Table("Signs");
```

**Handling exceptions**

```
    } catch (JsonIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As this seems to be an UI application, **don't simply print the stacktrace of an exception**. I doubt that the users are able to see the stack trace in the output, and even if they could, most of them would have no idea what it a `JsonIOException` means. Instead, provide appropriate error messages in dialogs.

**Empty else**

On one occasion you have this:

```
                } else {

                }
```

The else is not needed since it doesn't do anything there. If you plan on doing something there, add a `// TODO: Fix this` (but with a better message to yourself than "Fix this" otherwise you will have a hundred "Fix this" sooner or later - trust me, I've seen it happen). If you believe that an `else` cannot happen, either throw an exception or show an error message telling you that it actually **did** happen.

**Long method**

A very common [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) is to have a very long method. Although very common with methods that are initializing layouts, consider splitting your `initLayout` method in multiple pieces.

**public static PuntobileUI INSTANCE**

This tells me that your `PuntobileUI` is a singleton. Although singletons are handy sometimes, using UI-singletons regularly breaks the [Tell-Don't-Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) principle. I prefer to inform objects about "this is my PuntobileUI instance" rather than having the objects use a singleton instance. By referencing a singleton instance from other classes, you make your code less independent and increase the [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) of your classes which is generally bad because it reduces code re-usability.